# Best approach to use new .ico image for my sharepoint online site collections without the need to modify the seatle.master

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage, online

I am working on an office 365 sharepoint online 2013. and inside the web application i have 2 site collections; Team site collection & Enterprise Wiki site collection.

now i need to update their ico images. i found some articles such as [link](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/06/13/how-to-add-a-favicon-to-a-sharepoint-site-aspx/) which show how to do so by updating the master page. but i am trying to find a solution which do not require master page modification?
second question. is the ico image provided per web application or per site collection/master page? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would try using pure javascript

```
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

The script above will try to get the element or create it if it not exist. Use it into a JQuery - document ready function

Greetings

Comment: and where i need to reference this query !! i am back to the same problem..

Comment: you can add it into a Content Editor web part

Comment: and then i need to add the content editor web part on all the pages !!

Comment: If you dont want to edit the master page, yes, you have to do that on every single page. That's why we work with master pages, if we need to execute something across all pages we attach it to the master page.

Comment: but i am trying not to modify the built-in master page for my sharepoint online. as many articles i read suggest not to modify the master pages for SP online. because we might lose some new features which might be added to the master page in the future ..So if we custom the master page by creating a copy of the built-in master pages then we will lose these new features.. unless we manually apply these new features inside our custom master page..

Comment: I get your point, but when they talk about modify, they talk about to perform a full change to the master. But change the location of the fav icon will not present a problem in the future, because you will not change nothing but an url. If you insist to not touch the master, I think this is the best approach.

Comment: so what is the best approach you are referring to ?

Comment: also modifying a master page have multiple point of views; one is that if you create a copy of the seatle.master and you set the copy as the default master page , then i add the script inside the copy, then any future updates targeting the master page will be applied to the seatle.master, not to the copy so i will not benefit from the updates/new features.. while if i directly modify the seatle.master i will benefit from any future updates,, but in this case my modification will be overridden by the update .. this is my view on avoiding to directly modify the master pages...

Comment: I'm talking about the solution that I give you above. And I insist I get your point, but this is not a hardcore modification you will change only an url. Could you send us the articles you read about not modify the master?

Answer (score 2):

**use new .ico image for my SharePoint online site collections without the need to modify the Seattle.master**

Changing `favicon.ico` without modifying the Master Page will require developing a custom code to delegate a control in Master Page . Or via Javascript code that will also require modifying the master Page,

So if you need to achieve this without change the master page you will need to additional programming work for more details check [Change favicon without changing master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110467/change-favicon-without-changing-master-page)

So the simple method without using any code is editing the master page by doing the following :

- Open your site with SharePoint Designer
- Go to Site Assets
- Upload your new favicon.icon file
- Check in the file in the context menu and if asked publish the major version.
- Check out and edit the master page you're using
- Update the URL to the new favicon

In your master page locate the tag bellow:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
Replace it with:
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/favicon.ico" />
```

- Save the master
- Check in the file in the context menu and if asked publish the major version
- Refresh your site and the new favicon will appear

For more details check [How can I change the favicon on SharePoint and Office 365](https://support.bind.pt/hc/en-us/articles/204448259-How-can-I-change-the-favicon-on-SharePoint-and-Office-365-v2013-)

**is the icon image provided per web application or per site collection/master page?**

it's applied per site collection / master page

Comment: so which approach you suggest and which appraoch is  recommended in sharepoint, to do some development or to modify the master page ?

Comment: In SharePoint online, Microsoft recommends to don't modify the default master page but it didn't stop you from doing it if you want to. So, if you are making master page changes, it’s up to you  so I have mentioned both javascript and modify master page in my answer and I suggest if you already have more modification in you custom page to match your business continue with this approach,if you need only to modify the master page for this purpose use javascript,meanwhile if you have modified the master page you should stay up to date with the ongoing product updates applied to SharePoint Online.

Comment: not i have not modify the master page for our SP online project till now

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont want to modify the masterpage, the easiest & simplest method would be `User Custom Actions`. Also, since this looks like a one time activity, you can write a console application using `CSOM C#` to execute a javascript file on each page of the site collection. In the javascript file, we can add the code to modify the favico.

Try the below code:

```
UserCustomActionCollection collUserCustomAction = context.Web.UserCustomActions;
UserCustomAction userCustomAction = collUserCustomAction.Add();
userCustomAction.Location = "ScriptLink";                
userCustomAction.Sequence = 9;
userCustomAction.ScriptSrc = "sitecollectionurl/SiteAssets/InsertFavIcon.js";                
userCustomAction.Title = "Fav ico";
userCustomAction.Description = "Insert fav icon javascript";
userCustomAction.Update();
context.Load(userCustomAction);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Inside the `InsertFavIcon.js`, the code to change favico would be as below:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('favicon'); 
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); //removes SharePoint OOTB favico
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'path-to-sitecoll/SiteAssets/favicon.ico';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Also, if you don't want to write a console application, you can write SharePoint hosted app or add code inside script editor/content editor webpart which will register the custom action. Code would be as below. This is a pure javascript based implementation:

```
function AddCustomActions() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var site = clientContext.get_web();
    var UserCustomActions = site.get_userCustomActions();

    var newUserCustomAction = UserCustomActions.add();
    newUserCustomAction.set_location('ScriptLink');
    newUserCustomAction.set_scriptSrc('sitecollectionurl/SiteAssets/InsertFavIcon.js');
    newUserCustomAction.set_sequence(9);
    newUserCustomAction.set_title('Favico');
    newUserCustomAction.set_description('Insert favico javascript');
    newUserCustomAction.update();

   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    console.log('New favico added to Site.');
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
AddCustomActions()
```

This will inject the javascript on each page. Also, keep in mind, this will not work on lists/libraries page(like allitems.aspx) if you have "New" list/libraries experience enabled as currently customizations are disabled on it.

Comment: "_Also, keep in mind, this will not work on lists/libraries page(like allitems.aspx) if you have "New" list/libraries experience enabled as currently customizations are disabled on it._" i did not get your point on this? second question you mentioned to injected the JavaScript on all the pages ,, so now if I have an enterprisewiki site collection,,and users will keep adding new pages,, so how i will be injecting the javascript on these new wiki pages? or i can inject the javascript the page layout ?

Comment: Regarding 1st point, check this link - https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/25/modern-sharepoint-lists-are-here-including-integration-with-microsoft-flow-and-powerapps/

Comment: Regarding new pages, the user custom action will be applied to them. You don't have to do anything now. User custom action ensures that your script is executed on each page of the site. So whenever you create a new page, this js file will be executed there as well

Comment: You can inject script using c# console app with Microsoft.SharePoint.client dll or inside a page/ page layout as I have mentioned in the answer. Since its a onetime activity, I would suggest console app.

Comment: so i will use c# console app to execute the above UsercustomAction , and then will upload the script. this should chnage the fav.ico for all the pages inside the current site collection. of course i do not want to edit the master page to do so because my question is about changing the fav.ico without modifying the master page   . my approach should work except for the  "_lists/libraries page(like allitems.aspx) if you have "New" list/libraries experience enabled as currently customizations are disabled on it_" is this correct ?

Comment: First upload the script in site collection and then run console app. Yes should work on all pages except modern pages

Comment: but can you please advice if it is worth to do all these modifications to change the .ico image? , or it will be simpler to just modify the master page directly ? can i know your opinion ?

Comment: Yes its the "new" way of developing things for SharePoint online. Microsoft has recommended us not to modify/use masterpages. So we have to do script/css injection. This is not about just favico. You should add all js/css files using the injection method instead of using custom masterpage or modifying seattle masterpage. Cant find a link for it, but some time future SharePoint online update, the ability to customize masterpage  will be removed. So better to use this method now instead of scrambling later to save a project

Comment: Works perfectly!