# Strange behavior of FAVICON

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, branding

After we have updated our SharePoint 2013 farm with the Sept 2017 CU we have the following situation:

Some users see the default SP favicon, some see our custom favicon. 
When checking with the \15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES folder on both our web front ends the folder shows the default icon. When opening it in Paint we see the custom one!

[image]

- When copying the new/custom favicon I'm being asked if I want to replace it - if I do it still shows up with the default logo (double-clicking shows the custom one).

Is there anywhere else I can or should look to replacing the favicon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked any other icons with the file extensions .ico to see if they display differently to? Does the modify date for the file show anything? Interesting!

Comment: When I copy a brand new ICO file into that folder it still has the date of the original file. Interesting and annoying ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `Favicon` in the `\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES` is **not** a recommended solution, you will face unstable behavior as you have described

**To change `FAVICON`, you should do the following:**

- Open your site via SharePoint Designer.
- Go to Site Assets > Upload your new `favicon.icon` file
- Check in the file > Publish it as a major version.
- Go back to Master Page ( All files > _catalogs > masterpage) > Check out and edit the current master page in advanced mode.
- Find `<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon`.

  ```
   <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
  ```
- Update the `IconUrl` with the new URL.

  ```
   <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/favicon.ico" />
  ```
- Save, Check in and publish the Master Page as a major version.
- Reset IIS (optional) and clear the cache.
- Refresh your site, the new `favicon` should be now updated and worked properly.

---

**If you don't need to change the Master Page, try the below alternatives**

- Using `delegation control` as mentioned at [Change favicon without changing master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110467/change-favicon-without-changing-master-page)
- Using `User Custom action` as mentioned at [Best approach to use new .ico image for my sharepoint online site collections without the need to modify the seatle.master](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199758/best-approach-to-use-new-ico-image-for-my-sharepoint-online-site-collections-wi/199800#199800)
  -

Comment: Will give it a try. However it worked with placing the icon on the server for the last 2 years without any issue whatsoever.

Comment: I think because you have patched your farm with new CU!

Comment: Making the changes to the Master Page solved our issue. Still a strange behaviour. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found this approach (change IronUrl) no longer work on SP2016. See my another question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266943/cannot-form-a-correct-iconurl-in-html-master-page/266946?noredirect=1#comment283838_266946