# Cannot form a correct IconUrl in Html master page

Tags: 2016, master-page, site-logo

We are using SharePoin 2016 on-premise.

I have uploaded our custom favicon to site assets at Url:
https://sharepoint.com/sites/abc/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png

In my HTML master page I added this line:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png"/>-->
```

And end up in the SharePoint page it is requesting for:
https://sharepoint.com/sites/pm/~sitecollection/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png?rev=40

Yes, `~sitecollection` become part of URL string. I have tried many different combination and all rendered to different funny result. Could you give me a working example for SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 0):

First try adding Full/Absolute URL of icon as below:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="https://sharepoint.com/sites/abc/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png" />
```

If it is working then try adding relative URL like this (If icon is stored on top level site: `https://sharepoint.com`):

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png" />
```

**Or** you can store this icon file in `/_layouts/15/images folder` where the original/default favicon is stored and use it like:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/Logo48x48.png" />
```

**Or** you can store this icon file in master page gallery and use it like:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_catalogs/masterpage/images/Logo48x48.png" />
```

Comment: I tried full url and it is working. When I tried /SiteAssets/xxxx as you mentioned, it return URL https://sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png"

Comment: You are using this icon for only one site collection or you are going to use if for all site collections?

Comment: I think it is because o365's site url do not have /sites/xxx/ suffix?

Comment: I want to use the same Master page for all site collections. I will upload icon to each site collection's SiteAssets library

Comment: I Guess then it is better to upload this icon at one place at tenant level top site i.e. `sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/images/Logo48x48.png` for better re-usability.

Comment: sharepoint.com and sharepoint.com/sites/abc are 2 different site collections in SP2016 on-premise

Comment: Then is it possible for you to put this icon file in `/_layouts/15/images` folder? Where the original/default favicon is stored.

Comment: Then you can add it like `<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images /Logo48x48.png" />`.

Comment: I think it will work. However I need to upload them to each WFE and not easy to update in the future. I will try and see if any other solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check by adding this icon in master page gallery and referencing it from there? See updated answer if it works for you.

Comment: /_catalogs/masterpage/images/Logo48x48.png will be rendered to  https://sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage/images/Logo48x48.png which is wrong url