# favicon is not working SharePoint Online site using HTML master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage, branding, html

I'm using HTML master page for SharePoint online site. To show favicon i have included the below code in HTML master page,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://siteurl/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

But is not showing any icon in the browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try by using <link rel='shortcut icon' href='/SiteAssets/favicon.ico' /> and  publish  the html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to do the following:**

- Upload your icon to `Site Assets`
- In your Master Page file locate the tag bellow:

  ```
  <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
  ```
- Replace it with:

  ```
  <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/favicon.ico" />
  ```
- Save and Check-In.

> **Note:** In SharePoint online, Microsoft recommends to don't modify the
>   default master page but it didn't stop you from doing it if you want
>   to do. So, if you need to change the icon without changing the master
>   page try to  create a **delegate control** as mentioned at
>   [Best approach to use new .ico image for my sharepoint online site collections without the need to modify the seatle.master](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199758/best-approach-to-use-new-ico-image-for-my-sharepoint-online-site-collections-wi/199770#199770)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using HTML master page I can't edit .master file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `shortcut` from `rel`. It is non-conforming and may be causing the line of code to get kicked out on render. Design Manager is picky about clean code.

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://siteurl/favicon.ico">
```